# GWAN Floating point exception

Tags: c, exception, webserver, g-wan

When trying to run GWAN on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS I sometimes get the "Floating point exception" error. Sometimes it will happen many times in a row, and it can start and run fine a few times in a row. But it always happens now and then, seems to be random..

Comment: Your problem description is not very clear, but look out for divisions by uninitialised integer variables. Turning up the compiler warnings with `-Wall` might already do the job of finding the error source. (In my experience, floating-point exceptions rarely occur with floating-point values; they just end up as infinity or NaN values. But integer divisions by zero are a strong contender here.)

Comment: The question is not clear: please clarify what you did and what gave "Floating point exception"? Did you run your C script and get the error? Did you just run G-WAN and get the error (and G-WAN won't start)? For the later, http://gwan.com/faq#cpus .

Answer (score 0):

Nagi's questions above are relevant: it would help to know under which conditions you are using G-WAN.

The [link](http://gwan.com/faq#cpus) Nagi provided is also relevant but if you were facing a script error then the crash would be constant.

There's another known case which may lead to an *erratic* floating point error at startup, and that's [hypervisors](http://gwan.com/faq#hypervisors).

You are most probably experiencing the second case, for which workarounds have been implemented in May last year (`G-WAN v4.5+`).

Taking place between the hardware and the OS, many hypervisors are breaking the CPU description reported by the Linux kernel, and they also happen to break CPU features(!) and system features like timers, memory allocation, etc.

In short, you are likely to use `G-WAN v4.3.28` and need to upgrade to a more recent release. We give more recent releases to registered users and people who contribute to the project with code, ideas, etc.

The next public release will be make available after our G-WAN-based Cloud services are shipped (later this year).